# How to Compute Norm of Matrix?

Tags: rotations, matrix-norms

While looking into the camera rotation dataset, I had found a $3\times3$ rotation matrix $R$ which has very slight change from original :
$$R=\begin{bmatrix}
0.99995284&-0.01584106&-0.01266612\\
-0.0045012&0.99991074&-0.01571224\\
0.01275538&0.01563972&0.99979431\end{bmatrix}$$

I'd like to calculate the distance this one from the $3\times3$  identity matrix but had never learned a unary operation which maps $\Bbb R^{m\times n} \to \Bbb R$.

Which way could I adpot to calculate one?

Comment: Would the angle of rotation be a reasonable measure of the distance from the identity? It satisfies $1+2\cos\theta=\textrm{trace}(R)$.

Comment: The easiest-to-compute [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) is the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm), which is equivalent to treating an $m\times n$ matrix as an $mn$-dimensional vector and taking its Euclidean norm.

Comment: @Rahul any other? I'd like to horizontally compare within the exhaustive list of actually-used matrix norms in the field of optimization

Comment: There are lots of them listed in the page on matrix norms I linked to. That said, I believe the Frobenius norm is indeed used a lot in optimization.

Comment: The Frobenius norm will always evaluate to $\sqrt{3}$ for a rotation matrix, since $\|A\|_F = \sqrt{ trace( A^TA )}$. You could use the Frobenius metric, to measure the distance from the identity, however.

Answer (score 1):

The rotation matrices form a Lie group, which is a manifold in the set of all $3\times 3$ matrices. Ideally, you need a metric which gives you the geodesic distance between two matrices.

The tangent space of the $3\times 3$ rotation matrices is the set of $3\times 3$ skew-symmetric matrices, which can be obtained using the exponential map. This allows us to define the geodesic metric using the tangent space,
$$
  \rho(R_1,R_2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\| \log(R_1^{-1}R_2)\|_F
$$

Note that the $\log$ function is the matrix logarithm.